# Abstract Firebase from Android UI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing with issue that Firebase as Realtime Database works great while we connect it with Activity or Fragment. But trying to separate from view elements and create some abstraction for it (because e.g. we want to replace it while testing or in the future) becomes quite hard, especially trying to implement MVP pattern.

Are there any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried FirebaseUI library?

Comment: Please add some code example.

Comment: @ugboz If I want to change implementation I will have to rewrite whole code because it will be impossible to replace FirebaseUI

Comment: Never do that.  Use interfaces to provide connection between data and ui.

Comment: Of course, but with FirebaseUI it will be very hard.

Comment: Please add some code. Abstraction is independent from any language and any platform. You may miss somethings.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no inherent coupling between Firebase and UI (unless you're using `FirebaseUI`).  Typical solution would be to encapsulate firebase database access in some kind of Service/DAO class (injected in to UI classes using Dagger for example)....and have methods in that class return RxJava Observable (this also nicely enables making sets of nested firebase queries....for example if doing something equivalent to a "join")

Answer (score -1):

Just save a string value in your resources and save your DB path
Then when you create a `DatabaseReference` use that value to point to the base of either your real or test DB