# Android - Getting an Object from DataSnapShot - firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a helper class including the functions and processes I would like to perform over my data in FirebaseDatabase.

The following function was meant to get all Posts in posts Node in fireabseDataBase:

```
public static Jobs getAllJobs() {

    Posts posts= new Posts();
    postsDBRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts").getRef();

    postsDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot jobSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // TODO: handle the post
               String key = jobSnapshot.getKey();
               //here 
               Post post= jobSnapshot.child(key).getValue(Post.class);
              // and here  
               posts.add(post);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i(getClass().getName().toString(), ": " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return posts;
}
```

in the `onDataChange` function I am trying to loop over the data and retrieve it, although while logging I do get data but the post object keeps giving Null

Here's How the data look like in firebase DataBase

```
 {
  "posts" : {
    "-Kr9-ii-ArpC3fLuuGnb" : {
      "address" : "sfhhfg",
      "applied" : false,
      "currency" : "le",
      "description" : "ehdhyf",
      "latitude" : 0,
      "longitude" : 0,
      "noOfWorkers" : 2,
      "rating" : 0,
      "reported" : false,
      "salary" : "1250",
      "title" : "rgchu",
      "userId" : 0
    },
    "-Kr94BDkdEZrmxmjxv_Z" : {
     /../
    },
    "-Kr9Dz3S0BQEYv4VO2l3" : {
   /../
    },
    "-Kr9XqDPUvCRcv0lwFy_" : {
    /../
    }
  }
}
```

and here’s what am getting from the Debugger in a single loop

> DataSnapshot { key = -Kr9-ii-ArpC3fLuuGnb, value = {address=sfhhfg,
>   rating=0, title=rgchu, reported=false, description=ehdhyf, userId=0,
>   longitude=0, noOfWorkers=2, latitude=0, currency=le, applied=false,
>   salary=1250} }

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: We have no way to know what `getDataBaseReference("posts")` returns, nor can we know what the JSON at `posts` look like. Please make sure that your questions contains the [minimum complete information that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you share JSON, be sure to share it as text (no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added extra info, thanks for pointing out to the missing info

Comment: `getReference("posts").getRef()` -> `getReference("posts")`. The result is the same, but it would've saved me a double-take.

Comment: We still have no idea what `Post` is, but it seems likely it doesn't match your JSON. Please reduce both the class and the JSON to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. For example: it is likely that you can reproduce it with one or two properties, which saves quite some space and time.

Comment: Also: I assume `key` gets the proper value for each child snapshot. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: firstly, Post is a POJO class with default constructor, setters and getters of each property.
Secondly, Posts are Pushed to the dataBase to create a unique key for each that's why am retrieving them by keys
Here's how I create a single Post

 public static void createJob(Post post) {
        //post created and pushed to the DB
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        postsDBRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("posts").push();
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

After several trials

```
.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Job job = snapshot.getValue(Job.class);
                    System.out.println(job.getTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i(getClass().getName().toString(), ": " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Using .addChildEventListener was the only Solution for my issue, Still investigation the reason.

Answer (score 0):

i have edited your code and it should work fine now, i have used the same code snippets in several projects before. make sure your pojo matches the json data, you can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) tool to make it easier for yourself.

and the most important thing , Don't use Firebase as functions that return values - it goes against it's asynchronous nature.make Firebase perform it's task and then within the closure (block) go to the next step.

P.S: before using `ValueEventListener` or `ChildEventListener` read the difference between them from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069813/2968988).

```
public void getAllJobs() {

Posts posts= new Posts();

postsDBRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

postsDBRef.child("posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot jobSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
           Post post= jobSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
           posts.add(post);
        }
     // go to next step from here e.g handlePosts(posts);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName().toString(), ": " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});

}
```