# Android - Firebase database child node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase databse structure like this :

[the firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I3z7.png)

Now I want to access the items in the node "comingSoonPages" to a model class. How can i get the reference to these different user specified items in that node?

The database reference :

```
mUpcomingDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("comingSoonPages").child("blrKoramangala")
```

now the listener to the reference is as :

```
mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.e("snap" , String.valueOf(snapShot));
            try{
                UpcomingProperty property = snapShot.getValue(UpcomingProperty.class);
                Log.e("name" , String.valueOf(property.getName()));
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
mUpcomingDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
```

when i try to log the names in each of the nodes , i get NPE and the value is null.

The model class in which i am mapping is :

```
public class UpcomingProperty implements Serializable {

    //private Amenities amenities;
    private List<String> amenities;
    private Coordinates coordinates;
    private Image image;
    private String link;
    private String location;
    private String name;
    private Text text;
    private List<String> sortParameter;
    private EarlyBird earlyBird;

    public UpcomingProperty(){}

    public List<String> getAmenities() {
        return amenities;
    }

    public void setAmenities(List<String> amenities) {
        this.amenities = amenities;
    }

    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Text getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(Text text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public List<String> getSortParameter() {
        return sortParameter;
    }

    public void setSortParameter(List<String> sortParameter) {
        this.sortParameter = sortParameter;
    }

    public EarlyBird getEarlyBird() {
        return earlyBird;
    }

    public void setEarlyBird(EarlyBird earlyBird) {
        this.earlyBird = earlyBird;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

the extended firebase node :
[extended node values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsnz3.png)

Comment: What do you want actually to display? The name of the nides? `blkKaramangala`, `cyberHub` and so on?

Comment: @AlexMamo the nodes and values inside these blkKaramangala, cyberHub

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to display the data inside these nodes "blkKaramangala, cyberHub"

Comment: `blkKaramangala` and `cyberHub` have simmilar structures? All those nodes, have the same childrens inside?

Comment: yes @AlexMamo all the nodes like blkKaramangala and so on having the same structure

Comment: Then see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference comingSoonPagesRef = rootRef.child("comingSoonPages");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
comingSoonPagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The out will be the only the names. But you can get also all the other values in the same way.

If you want to use the model class, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference comingSoonPagesRef = rootRef.child("comingSoonPages");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            UpcomingProperty upcomingProperty = ds.getValue(UpcomingProperty.class);
            Log.d("TAG", upcomingProperty.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
comingSoonPagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

You'll have the same output.

Comment: thanks a lot man , actually i had tried the same way that you have explained .. but it was not working and i was getting an NPE for that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `comingSoonPages` holds a list of item, You need to add a [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) on the `comingSoonPages` reference if you want to access all the child nodes of that.

```
DatabaseReference upcomingItemsRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("comingSoonPages");

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
         if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
             // Handle each individual node like blrKoramangala, cyberHub here.
             String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
             // Get the UpcomingProperty object here.
             UpcomingProperty property = dataSnapshot.getValue(UpcomingProperty.class);
             Log.d(TAG, "property.getName():" + property.getName();
         }
     }
     // Other methods of ChildEventListener go here
};
upcomingItemsRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

You can read more about working with lists of data [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data).

However, if that's not a list, here's what you're doing wrong:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Don't do this. It will get the children of blrKoramangala and
    // those won't be of UpcomingProperty type. 
    // Remove and replace with dataSnapshot.exists()
    for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you getting the keys , but what's the use of it ??

Comment: the key will give the String `blrKoramangala`, `cyberHub` etc. Use it only if you need it.

Comment: its the same error "Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type" with null value in the name variable

Comment: Can you please add the image expanding `amenities` and `sortParameter`?

Comment: your variable names are stored as keys to the data mapping to them.

Comment: Also, please add the complete exception message that you're getting  `Cannot convert java.util.ArrayList to type .........`

Comment: please check the updated question , i have added a screenshot

Comment: In your new screenshot I notice that you've not used double quotes properly. If you're storing Strings then put them like this `"This is a String"` i.e. in double quotes. Place only integers and double without quotes. You've not closed the double quotes.

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept (and upvote) the answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Btw, you should prefer using ChildEventListener over ValueEventListener as per the documentation and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069813/4857588